# forms authentication - no logout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Usually I have:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
   timeout="30"
   slidingExpiration="true"
</authentication>
```

which (IMHO) means that the cookie expires after 30 minutes of inactivity - sliding expiration means that any activity sets the cookie's expiry time back to 30 minutes.

Now I have the requirement that I would like the cookie to be stored indefinately, unless the user logs out explicitly. This means, that even if the browser is closed and reopened and the user goes to a side that requires authentication, no login is required. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-forms-based-website-authentication#477579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe sounds equivalent to forcing the *remember me* checkbox to always be checked. To achieve that, go to your your `Login` action, and do the following:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that's it. I always thought that is remember me as in maintain login form's data.

Comment: The timeout will still be respected, however. You could change it to `525949` (one year), or something, too.

Answer (score 0):

use `SetAuthCookie` method.   [SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx)

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserID, false); // not persisting cookie accross the browser session.
```

FormsAuthentication.SignOut().// for signout